# Virtualbox installation screen size too small

Tags: system-installation, virtualbox

Virtualbox installation doesn't show a proper sized screen, so no controls are available to continue

Answer (score 2):

Checking the "Enable EFI" under System / Motherboard resolved it for me.

From the better boot experience I am going to be checking this box on all future Linux builds.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely the same with VMWare. Seems that installer sets 800x600 resolution in virtual environment.

[image]

Comment: Confirmed! Thanks a lot!