# Can't install elementaryOS in virtualbox as guest screen 800x600

Tags: resolution, install, virtualbox

I'm trying to install elementaryOS 6 in a virtual box but I can't get passed the 'install' options on booting the ISO because the bottom/right side of the screen is cut off as it's defaulting to a Guest screen resolution of 800x600.

I can't install the Virtualbox Guest Additions, because the elementaryOS ISO is attached to the virtualCD and can't be ejected.

I tried adding a secondary virtual CD but that just didn't work.

How am I meant to install elementaryOS if the 800x600 screen resolution prevents me progressing through the installer? I can't install the Virtualbox Guest Additions because elementaryOS is in the virtual CD device?

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution from this thread : [Virtualbox installation screen size too small](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/28511/virtualbox-installation-screen-size-too-small/28552#28552?newreg=88f5825233e840aba4b3e78086f1a137)

---

Go to Settings > System > Motherboard > Extended features, check "[] Enable EFI (special OSes only)"

(It may require the extension pack available on [VirtualBox - Downloads page](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads), I downloaded it but I not sure it's required)

[image]

---

Have a nice day :-)

Greg

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve my issue by changing the Virtualbox Display Graphics Controller for my elementaryOS virtual machine to the non-default "VBoxVGA"  (the default being "VMSVGA") and ignoring the warning about changing from the default.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the Virtualbox Display Graphics Controller for my elementaryOS virtual machine to the non-default "VBoxSVGA" also worked.  HOWEVER, I had problems until I installed the Virtualbox Extension Pack.  I recently updated to Virtualbox 6.1 and was not automatically prompted to reinstall the extension, which prevented me selecting any graphics controller other than VMSVGA.  After installing the extensions I changed the graphics controller and ElementaryOS installed fine.